# Are lawsuit records publicly available?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, court, foia

I was a witness in a trial back in 2012, representing the plaintiff who was fired illegally. https://www.kafourymcdougal.com/a-washington-county-jury-awards-nearly-1-million-to-esd-whistleblower-2012-08-10/

I want to use this as proof that the verdict was official, and the district was found to be in the wrong.

I'm looking for more than just the link I provided, like any written or spoken testimonies, stenotyped transcripts, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when searching for court records, you want to Google with the county name, state and "court" and that will get you the state district court. Of course, if the case was in federal court, try the PACER system: [Find a Case (PACER) | United States Courts](http://www.uscourts.gov/court-records/find-case-pacer).

In your case, Washington County (OR) Court records are available here: [Records - Washington County Court Records Department](http://www.courts.oregon.gov/Washington/Services/Records/pages/records.aspx)